# Show local files in Android

Tags: android, webview

I would like to show a content of that files: pdf, word, excel, txt, jpeg, bmp, png, tiff, but I don't know how to do that. On the iOS e.g. UIWebView control can show all that file types, but WebView control on Android not, not even tiff images, but the tiff is most important for me, or eventually pdf. I tried to find any free library for commercial use, but without success, I found only that library https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library, but it does not work with my example pdfs. I tested it on Android 2.3.3.
Is there any possibility to open such files?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520009/android-load-pdf-inside-webview

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but it opens pdf with 3rd pary application, not mine, I need to show that files in my app, the user may not have any application installed on the phone to open the file.

Comment: You can look at how the stock Browser makes use of WebView and accomplishes some of the viewing capabilities https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser/tree/froyo-release/src/com/android/browser other than that you'll have to code your custome viewers for things that are not supported. WebView's task is limited to rendering HTML/CSS/JS.