# Pdf view android studio

Tags: android, pdf, plugins, view

Hello community wanted to know how to view a PDF file in android api eight studio try these codes but can not = (someone tell me what's wrong? ..
I get all the WebView blank
  thanks

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //view.loadUrl(url);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });
           wv.loadUrl("www.ues.mx/Docs/alumnos/movilidad/Ejemplo%20de%20Curr%C3%ADculum%20Vitae.pdf");

    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

another way

```
   WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
         webview.loadUrl("www.ues.mx/Docs/alumnos/movilidad/Ejemplo%20de%20Curr%C3%ADculum%20Vitae.pdf");
    setContentView(webview);
```

PluginsEnabled replaced

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

not work in any way help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebView` cannot display PDF documents in Android.

You can handle the pdf to either download it and then open a 3rd party app as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10521218/451951).

Or you can also use Google Drive viewer.

```
String myPdfUrl = "http://example.com/awesome.pdf";
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;
Log.i(TAG, "Opening PDF: " + url);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: @ArielN.Mogro: you get an error when trying to add some extremely basic debug logging? Better read up on Log: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html